# In Android is there a proper way to Detect if user added or deleted fingerprint when app is in running or in close state?

Tags: android, fingerprint, android-fingerprint-api

I have gone through many links and codebase but answer is not convincing or full proof. Following link is there but also not convincing.

[How to Identify Fingerprint is add/edit/deleted from the android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41996310/how-to-identify-fingerprint-is-add-edit-deleted-from-the-android-device)

Is there a way to get fingerprint count? HasEnrolledFingerPrint() method is now deprecated.

Help appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

[KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/7ea5090/keystore/java/android/security/KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException.java) would be thrown when the SecretKey is used, if a new fingerprint is added or all the fingerprints are removed after the key was created. But from what I've seen, only a bunch of Samsung devices actually throw this exception. So it probably is not reliable enough if you want to know any change in the enrolled fingerprints across all devices.

If you're concerned about the security side of things, check out the [setInvalidatedByBiometricEnrollment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/keystore/KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder.html#setInvalidatedByBiometricEnrollment(boolean)) method which is available on N and above.